# Rails Neo4j query returning CypherRelationship instead of relationship values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j.rb

I'm working on a Rails application that tracks transactions between addresses, using Neo4j as the database. When I try to run this query:

```
Neo4j::Session.query("MATCH (sender:Address {address: 'abc123'})-[transaction:SENT_TO]->(receiver:Address) RETURN sender, transaction, receiver").to_a
```

I get back an array, as expected, but the `transaction` item returns as a CypherRelationship pointer rather than a struct of its properties like it does for the sender and receiver addresses:

```
=> [#<struct sender=#<Address uuid: nil, address: "abc123", user_tags: nil>, transaction=CypherRelationship 30, receiver=#<Address uuid: nil, address: "xyz321", user_tags: nil>>]
```

If I try to get one of the transaction properties by doing something like `transaction.props['amount']` it causes a new Cypher query to run. Since there are multiple properties I want to get back on each transaction, and a large number of transactions that will be returned, I would like for the initial query to simply return the properties of the relationship as a struct within the array.

This works how I want it to when I run the query directly in Neo4j, so I suspect it's an issue with the neo4j-core gem (or my use of it)... any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Neo4j and Neo4j-core gems provide object representations of nodes and relationships, but *which* object you'll wind up with depends entirely on the classes defined within your app. When a node or relationship is returned, the Neo4j gem attempts to locate a model that is responsible for it based on labels or  rel type. When one is found, it returns an instance of that class; when one is not found, it returns an instance of one of the basic classes provided by Neo4j-core: `CypherNode` or `CypherRelationship`.

In your case, you're not getting structs of properties, you're getting structs of nodes of type `Address`, since you have that model defined, and `CypherRelationship`, so you don't have a model defined for that type of relationship. Instances of your models have convenience methods for getting and setting properties but instances of `CypherNode` and `CypherRelationship` do not, so call `props` and you'll have access to the relationship's properties.

You might want to take a look at the `CypherRelationship` code. https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_relationship.rb is the bulk of it but it inherits from https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j/relationship.rb, which is mostly an abstract class but it also provides a few other methods. It has a pretty basic public interface, mostly convenience methods for working with the relationships. `CypherNode` is very similar: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_node.rb.

In general, my recommendation is to define models using `Neo4j::ActiveRel` for any relationships that you plan on working with as objects in Ruby. You can find the docs for it at http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/v7.0.2/ActiveRel.html.

Two other notes:

- You will receive Structs instead of instances of `CypherNode`/`CypherRelationship` or your model classes if your query is instructed to return properties instead of complete objects.
- If you use the Cypher DSL instead of passing the query in, you can use the `pluck` method and receive Arrays of objects instead of structs, if you'd like. `return(symbols).to_a` will work, too.

---

```
Neo4j::Session.current.query
      .match("(sender:Address {address: {addr} })-[transaction:SENT_TO]->(receiver:Address)")
      .params(addr: 'abc123')
      .pluck(:sender, :transaction, :receiver)
```